# Computer crashed and nothing seems to work

Tags: windows-8.1

So my desktop is slightly older, I had purchased it 3 or 4 years ago off of someone getting rid of their gaming pc. I have experienced very few problems with it over the years but woke up today to constant bsod's that are telling me to repair my pc.

The pc was running 8.1, so to start, I downloaded the iso from the Microsoft site (on my laptop) and created a bootable usb using cmd. When trying too boot from usb (with bios configured properly and also attempting to directly select it) it almost seems to be ignored and continues on to loading windows and then I get a bsod immediately after the windows logo.

I noticed around this point that I was only seeing 4gb of ram (I have 8gb installed [2x4gb]). As I have 6 slots, I started swapping the ram around and found one slot seemed to be toast.

Thinking I may have messed up the usb, I downloaded rufus as well as the Windows usb/DVD download tool. Both of those usb's lead to the same result.

I tried burning multiple discs and they all show as "no medium" when I boot to them.

My latest attempts have been to attempt to run ubuntu, both 18.04.2 and 10.04. While I can get to the main boot screen, upon selecting to run without install, it either just restarts my pc or white screens (respectively).

I should also add that I have tested all the usbs on my laptop to ensure they did work prior to using with my desktop. I even went as far as to try a win7 ultimate usb I had laying around. I was able to choose between 32 and 64 bit, it loaded and then in a black and white screen, showed the same error as the bsod.

I have poured over many forum posts and have tried many suggestions but I am feeling completely stuck and decided maybe making my own post may help.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In a situation like this, you need to go back to basics and do some detective work.  Start with the hardware.  Strip it down to the bare minimum and see if you can boot.  Then start adding components and verifying that they work.  Try exchanging parts to see if yours work on another system or other parts work on yours.  Typically, many different things don't fail at the same time, but if you start blindly making changes, you make it harder to figure out the original underlying problem.  Trying to solve this on a Q&A site will be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your advice fixer, I was hoping there could have been something on software end that I had missed. I am convinced myself it is hardware related so I will start the testing process.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware diagnostics by way of process of elimination is always a good place start. Case in point. Someone gave me a machine that they said would never boot after lightning struck right outside there house while the machine was on. I tried things for a couple hours till I started pulling things off the board and in short time pinpointed a shorted modem card.

I would also check the PSU. I have seen failing PSU's cause 4-5 problems at once or weird random things while on the way to failing but not yet all the way dead. A failing PSU not putting out its rated power can cause all kinds of strange things to happen by way of electrically starved circuitry. I would also run MEMtest86 and see if that shows a dead memory slot. You mentioned they all work but none of them work on one particular slot, I am not sure exactly how MEMtest86 works but if a slot went bad it will probably show error across the board where that module is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am now pretty convinced it has to be hardware related so I'll have to find some extra parts to start the process. I had ran memtest before and after fixing my ram problem, 24 million errors prior and 240k after so you are right that it does still show a lot of errors.